# Dropped table not showing up in recycle bin

Tags: oracle

I tried dropping a table and then when i viewed the recycle bin nothing was there in it . Earlier too i dropped tables many a times but I was surprised to find no objects whatsover in it .
What's the deal ?

**[update]**:

i had tried

```
   SHOW PARAMETER RECYCLEBIN;
```

Its VALUE column shows it  as ON . So fine here !

Then i droppped an existing table but still
the command

```
    Select object_name from recyclebin;
```

and any such retrieval of columns is showing `NO ROWS SELECTED` !!

Also using `flashback command`  confirms that recyclebin is not having any such dropped tables !!

So where are dropped tables going ?

And one more thing :

This time i tried using

```
 ALTER SYSTEM SET RECYCLEBIN=ON;
```

Instead of `Alter session`    and sqlplus throws an error :

`Specified initialization parameter is not modifiable with this option`

So, is this because  that i am working as a SYSTEM ??
i have not created any other USER as of now .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's likely that recyclebin isn't turned on. Check in your init.ora file to ensure it is. You can check your parameter:

```
select *
from   V$PARAMETER
where  NAME = 'recyclebin';
```

And turn it on at session level...

```
ALTER SESSION SET RECYCLEBIN=ON;
```

...and then try a drop.

Also, check both `USER_RECYCLEBIN` and `DBA_RECYCLEBIN` for entries.

EDIT: I see you've updated to say you are logged in as the `SYSTEM` user. For some reason, flashback/recyclebin does NOT work for `SYS`. I can't find a good reason why but it just doesn't. Create a new user and try creating and dropping a table while logged in as them. I'm sure you'll find that the recyclebin works fine then.

Comment: i cant find any relevant entries in this init.ora file for recycle bin and i ran the command but in that too  it seems nothing that i can do with it !!

Comment: Updated my answer to mention that flashback won't work in the `SYSTEM` tablespace.

Comment: yeah ,man  just came to update the same . But you already   did.

Comment: and i still don't understand the first command up there . Its neither working as SYSTEM user nor as any other user. So please edit it .

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the recycle bin is on and should be working.  The only thing I can think of is that you are using the `PURGE` option on your `DROP` commands -- is that the case?

The error you got from the `ALTER SYSTEM` command means exactly what it says -- the `RECYCLEBIN` option cannot be changed in that manner.  According to the documentation, you need to use the `DEFERRED` option, meaning that it will take effect for any new sessions but not for currently active ones.  But in any case, it sounds like the parameter is already on.

Comment: Indeed It is and i am not even touching PURGE as of now .